# "Looks as if" vs. "looks like as if"

Tags: as-like

Which one is preferable? I think the first one, but still:

> A: This tree looks strange.
>
> B: Yes, it looks **as if** it's going to fall.

vs.

> A: This tree looks strange.
>
> B: Yes, it looks **like as if** it's going to fall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With respect to the words at issue, grammatical sentences include:

> 1. It looks **as if** it's going to fall.
> 2. It looks **like** it's going to fall.

Since *like* and *as if* mean the same in the context of your sentence, it would be redundant and wrong to repeat them one after another.

---

In [the entry for the word *like*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/like_1?q=like), the Oxford Learner's Dictionary website contains the following caveat within the *Which Word?* usage note (modified):

> In informal English **like** is frequently used as an adverb instead of **as if**: *It looks like we’re going to be late.* This use of **like** is common but is not considered correct in formal written English.

---

To sum up, you're most likely to hear sentence number 2 in informal spoken/written English – meaning in most situations – but it'd be best to stick to sentence 1 (i.e., *as if*) if you're writing something formal, such as an academic article, official letter, school essay with such requirements, etc. Nevertheless, don't focus too much on this; you'll acquire the difference in register naturally if you keep being exposed to good English.

Also, **as though** is equivalent to **as if**, so sentence 1 could comfortably read:

> It looks **as though** it's going to fall.